# How to omit the parent class in css file

Tags: css, less

I have imported the a less file inside the parent class `e-js`. In this some of them is inside the parent element and some of them is out side of the parent element. But I have to import the less file inside the `e-js` code as I explained below.

**Less File**

```
.e-js {
    &.e-spreadsheet {
       display: none
    }
    .e-wrapper & {
       display: none;
    }
    .e-wrapper {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

**Actual CSS**

```
.e-js.e-spreadsheet {
    display: none;
 }
 .e-wrapper .e-js {
    display: none;
 }
 .e-js .e-wrapper {
    display: none;
 }
```

But I need the below code block, which omits the `.e-js` class. But in less file it is under `e-js`.

```
.e-wrapper {
   display: none;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in less??

Comment: Yes, don't put the code for .e-wrapper inside the block for .e-js.

Comment: i am asking about @at-root equivalent in less. is there anything available like that? other wise is there any way to select the parent level. i.e &1 for first parent, &2 for second parent.

Comment: I'm not _that_ familiar with less, but as I said, it's easy to produce the result you want in less: just don't put the code for `.e-wrapper` inside the block for `.e-js`. Put it after the block instead.